# IOS Keyboard input from computer

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard

I have an IOS application for which is would be really convenient for testing purposes if it could respond to keyboard strokes I make on my computer. Is there are way this is feasible?

More context: I have a custom keyboard I made with images which when touched prints the letter that was pressed. My custom keyboard however does not print the letters if I try typing them with my computer keyboard, only when I manually pressing them using the device or the simulator. Apples built in keyboard does this automatically for you, however it does not suite my needs for the application I wish to build.

So really my question is:

Is there a way to get input from a computer keyboard on an IOS device without it coming from the default Apple keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes there is a solution.

What I did:

I implemented the **UIKeyInpu**t protocol and the three methods that came with it:

```
public func insertText(text: String) {  } // <-- keyboard input comes in through here
public func deleteBackward() { }
public func hasText() -> Bool { return true; }
```

After that I did an override on the canBecomeFirstResponder method

```
public override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

And the last thing I did was call becomeFirstResponder method

```
self.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This should now allow you to receive keyboard input from the **insertText** method when you press keys on your keyboard on your computer (and possibly even the iPad, I have not tested this but I assume so).